# Pressing TAB key loses focus on widget

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a Table component in SWT. Whenever I edit a value in this table and press enter, this value is saved in the text component in this table.

But when I want to enter 2 words seperated with a TAB between them, then the editor loses focus and moves on to the next cell to edit(like pressing tab in a browser form). I don't want this to happen and let my users enter tabs between words without the focus getting lost. Anyone have an idea how to create this?

I allready tried using a keyListener, but it seems the tab event isn't even processed by this listener

Answer (score 5):

You could add a `TraverseListener` to your textField.

```
text.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener () {
        public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
            switch (e.detail) {
                case SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT:
                case SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS: {
                    e.doit = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Check out [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet127.java?view=co) example code snippet.

Comment: You should never post a link without any detail on its content. If the address is unreachable, your answer is worthless: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alex Stybaev but it seems that my table, column, widget does not implement the TraverseListener Interface

Comment: @bvanvelsen If you are really using the SWT `Table`, then you can use `table.addTraverseListener(listener)` as suggested by Alex.